# How to make a variable accessible from a subclass but not an instance java?

Tags: java

I have 3 classes. In 1 class I create an instance of a subclass inheriting from a superclass. How do I make my variables accessible to my subclass without it being available to the instance of the subclass? (Like static but only over multiple classes. I am new to java so at least that is how I think.)

```
public class Super {
    protected int myInt; //Struggling here
}

public class Sub {
    // Like to use the myInt in the super in a method here
}

public class MainPage {
    Sub obj = new Sub();
     int x = obj.myInt; //This should not happen
}
```

Comment: there is no inheritance in the provided example Also variables cannot be overridden only methods can be

Comment: The wording is not correct, an instance of `Sub` will always have access to `myInt` internally (if it extends `Super` which seems to be missing in your example). What you want is `MainPage`, or any other class which is not a subclass of `Super`, to not have access to `myInt`. In your example, when you do `obj.myInt`, it is `MainPage` that tries to access `myInt`, not `obj`

Comment: You may start with this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Protected scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is accessible from all classes in the same package, as well as subclasses in any package. Put `Super` and `Sub` in a separate one, and you have what you want (well, if `class Sub extends Super`).

From your example actually it is not clear, if package private (default) scope may also suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Place `public class MainPage` in a different package and you're all set.